# NIFI:Accessing rest api of kerberized nifi cluster

Tags: rest, sockets, apache-nifi

I want to  use  rest api(  but i don't  want to use curl command , i mean  i want  to use invokehttp procesor  for making post commands  to delete  queue flowfiles and start/stop processor ) I  used **Autorization Bearer Token** like this:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1LiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzLLRraGlsYWlzaHZpbGlAQ1JBLSd‌​LIiwiaXLzIjoiS2VyYmV‌​yb3LQcm92aWRlciIsImL‌​1ZCI6IStlcmJlcm9zUHJ‌​vdmlSZXIiLCJwcmVmZXJ‌​yZWRLdXLlcm5hbWUiOiJ‌​zLLRraGlsYWlzaHZpbGl‌​AQ1JBLSdLIiwia2lSIjo‌​1LCJleHAiOjE1MDQwMzA‌​2LTQsImlhdCI6MTUwMzS‌​4LzQ1LH0.VxxpvLQbGm3‌​H475g1yScvg5B89WSws3‌​lZUwBrUM4OvE
```

I  have added  autorization attribute in invokehttp and   added  link  like  this **https://server ip/nifi-api/acess/token** after this i   have added  another  invokehttp  with post  command and url like  this :**https://server ip/nifi-api/flowfile-queues/{id}/drop-requests**  (  p.s  i want to clear queue  from flowfile) but  first invokehttp   shows me exceptions like this :**Socket timeout  exception** and  there are  several  subject i am  interested in :

1. Is  it  possible that my  user  doesn't  have access to  berer token and that's why socket timeout  happens?  if it is  how can i checke  this.
2. if i have secured nifi is it  possible to use invokehttp processor without  ssl context service  to  fulfill this accsess/token  operation?
3. Do   you  have any better  idea to  rest api without  bearer token
   except using  ssl context service?

Answer (score 0):

1. `socket timeout` is a physical error not linked to auth
2. when auth is activated for nifi then you must use ssl context to access nifi-api
3. no. if auth activated on server side then client have to pass it.

Comment: is it  possible to use certificate path from nifi  properties  in ssl context service?

Comment: Can  you reccomened me any  post or article except nifi  documentations  about ssl context service

Comment: yes, you can. ssl context service in nifi is very simple object to specify where certificates stored to be used during https communication. i think you have to read about certificates basics.